# How to restructure json?

Tags: python, json, jq

So I have this json,I want to restructure it so far it's in a single array. Now I want to sort it according to the vendors.
Right now the structure is
key1
key2
key3

key1
key2
key3

```
{
  "id": "1335735520073232385",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST",
  "username": "kristinaforest",
  "tweet": "@iamsandyhall It’s the look of surprise on her face and the vulnerability on his "
  "vendor": "null"
}
{
  "id": "1335735456223399937",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:44 IST",
  "username": "openbugbounty",
  "tweet": "@lyrsense please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583432 on your website  "
  "vendor": "openbugbounty"
}
{
  "id": "1335735446496817152",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:41 IST",
  "username": "openbugbounty",
  "tweet": "@arstechnica please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583440 on your website  "
  "vendor": "openbugbounty"
}
{
  "id": "1335735260957564929",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST",
  "username": "tpwk_falls",
  "tweet": "2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us  @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN "
  "vendor": "zayn malik"
}
```

How do I restructure it to

```
[
  {
    "vendor": "openbugbounty",
    "tweets": [
        {
       "id": "1335735260957564929",
       "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST",
       "username": "tpwk_falls",
       "tweet": "2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with            
        honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us    
        @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever  
        supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN"
        },
       {
       "id": "1335735260957564929",
       "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST",
       "username": "tpwk_falls",
       "tweet": "2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with            
        honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us    
        @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever  
        supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN  "
        }
     ]
   },
 .....
```

Comment: your input is not valid JSON. Please, provide the correct sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `itertools.groupby`. But it has the extra overhead of sorting the lost first because if a list is like [1,1,2,2,1,3,3] then `groupby` will work as [(1,1), (2,2), (1), (3,3)], that is why sorting is required, obviously, you can do without groupby, but it makes the code simpler and can use if you do not care about time complexity.

```py
from itertools import groupby

l = [{
  "id": "1335735520073232385",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST",
  "username": "kristinaforest",
  "tweet": "@iamsandyhall It’s the look of surprise on her face and the vulnerability on his ",
  "vendor": "null"
},
{
  "id": "1335735456223399937",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:44 IST",
  "username": "openbugbounty",
  "tweet": "@lyrsense please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583432 on your website  ",
  "vendor": "openbugbounty"
},
{
  "id": "1335735446496817152",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:41 IST",
  "username": "openbugbounty",
  "tweet": "@arstechnica please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583440 on your website  ",
  "vendor": "openbugbounty"
},
{
  "id": "1335735260957564929",
  "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST",
  "username": "tpwk_falls",
  "tweet": "2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us  @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN ",
  "vendor": "zayn malik"
}]

sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['vendor'])
grouped = groupby(sorted_l, key=lambda x: x['vendor'])

output = []

for key, group in grouped:
    output.append({
        'vendor': key,
        'tweets': [{j:i[j] for j in i if j != 'vendor'} for i in group]
    })
    
print(output)
```

```
[{'vendor': 'null',
  'tweets': [{'id': '1335735520073232385',
    'created_at': '2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST',
    'username': 'kristinaforest',
    'tweet': '@iamsandyhall It’s the look of surprise on her face and the vulnerability on his '}]},
 {'vendor': 'openbugbounty',
  'tweets': [{'id': '1335735456223399937',
    'created_at': '2020-12-07 05:28:44 IST',
    'username': 'openbugbounty',
    'tweet': '@lyrsense please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583432 on your website  '},
   {'id': '1335735446496817152',
    'created_at': '2020-12-07 05:28:41 IST',
    'username': 'openbugbounty',
    'tweet': '@arstechnica please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583440 on your website  '}]},
 {'vendor': 'zayn malik',
  'tweets': [{'id': '1335735260957564929',
    'created_at': '2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST',
    'username': 'tpwk_falls',
    'tweet': '2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us  @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN '}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via collections defaultdict and iteration through your json

```
from collections import defaultdict

flat_json = [{
    "id": "1335735520073232385",
    "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST",
    "username": "kristinaforest",
    "tweet": "@iamsandyhall It’s the look of surprise on her face and the vulnerability on his ",
    "vendor": "null"
},
{
    "id": "1335735456223399937",
    "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:44 IST",
    "username": "openbugbounty",
    "tweet": "@lyrsense please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583432 on your website  ",
    "vendor": "openbugbounty"
},
{
    "id": "1335735446496817152",
    "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:41 IST",
    "username": "openbugbounty",
    "tweet": "@arstechnica please notify your IT security team about a security vulnerability OBB-1583440 on your website  ",
    "vendor": "openbugbounty"
},
{
    "id": "1335735260957564929",
    "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:27:57 IST",
    "username": "tpwk_falls",
    "tweet": "2 years into a song of vulnerability - a catchy melody embedded with honest lyrics opening up about a difficult time. Thank u for sharing with us  @zaynmalik I’m so proud of how far you’ve come and continue to go. Forever supporting ur journey #2yearsofgoodyears   PROUD OF ZAYN ",
    "vendor": "zayn malik"
}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in flat_json:
    vendor = item.pop('vendor')
    d[vendor].append(item)

result = [{'vendor': k, 'tweets': v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

array = '{ "id": "1335735520073232385", "created_at": "2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST", "username": "kristinaforest",  "tweet": "@iamsandyhall It’s the look of surprise on her face and the vulnerability on his ","vendor": "null"}'
data  = json.loads(array)
print(data['id'], data['created_at'])
[out]: 335735520073232385 2020-12-07 05:28:59 IST
```